# Active or Focus Effect on HTML< Ul> tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is a sample ul tag:

```
<ul style="list-style-type:none; padding:5px ; border:solid 1px #666666;">
    <li>I am wating </li>
    <li>I am wating </li>
    <li>I am wating </li>
    <li>I am wating </li>
    <li>I am wating </li>
```

Is there any way with css or JavaScript  to set this Ul border different color when it is clicked or active ?
And when I click in different place this effect gone . I was trying to make and search but not any good result came out .

Js Fiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/saifrahu28/YFF6P/

No problem also if there is any jquery solution .

Comment: do you have to use pure js?

Comment: I don't have any problem using any js but Actually I am no hat good with java script I am finding it difficult to make js for this Effect

Comment: in which case I would use the jquery library (makes javascript a lot easier) and add a class: http://jsfiddle.net/YFF6P/12/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Building off of FAngels answer....

You wouldn't want to hard code the list style, otherwise you will have to use !important in the css.  You change the tabindex to the UL and add a class to it.  When it has focus, it will change to the ul:focus item.

HTML

```
<ul tabindex="1" class="thisList" >
    <li>I am wating </li>
    <li>I am wating </li>
    <li>I am wating </li>
    <li>I am wating </li>
    <li>I am wating </li>

</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul:focus {
    outline:solid 1px green;
}

.thisList { list-style-type:none; padding:5px ; border:solid 1px #666666; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YFF6P/14/

Comment: :) This what I was trying to make . Thanks a lot . It is  just perfect

Comment: Not a problem.  I figured I could expand upon FAngel for you.

Answer (score 14):

You can add tabindex to each li. This will enable outline on it (basically, it will act like inputs in focus):

```
<ul style="list-style-type:none; padding:5px ; border:solid 1px #666666;">
        <li tabindex="1">I am wating </li>
        <li tabindex="1">I am wating </li>
        <li tabindex="1">I am wating </li>
        <li tabindex="1">I am wating </li>
        <li tabindex="1">I am wating </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YFF6P/2/

After that is done, you may change appearance of outline with `outline` property in css 
Here is with outline example: http://jsfiddle.net/YFF6P/4/
css:

```
li:focus {
    outline:solid 1px black;
}
```

Comment: Actually I am wanting the Ul border to make change li element should remain same how are they now .

Thanks

Comment: @user2355038 I'm sorry, but I do not understand your comment ^(

Comment: Or... Here is a solution for UL being focused when li clicked: http://jsfiddle.net/YFF6P/13/ (just remove tabindex from li's, add it to UL and create ul:focus style)

Comment: Ul tag have a border "border:solid 1px #666666; " I am wanting to change this border. li item don't need any effect actually .

Comment: See an example in my previous comment. Well, just one problem there: originally border is specified in style attribute which has higher priority than styles in CSS, so that is why I have !important there

Comment: I would avoid using !important if possible.. just by moving the style into a class.

Answer (score 0):

li:active, .test li:focus{border: 1px solid red;}

Why not just use the jQuery addClass() function ?

Comment: Because the author isn't using jQuery.

Comment: But he can use javascript...

li.className = li.className + " focusClass";

Comment: :) problem is I am not really very good with js or jquery . How to add this function there ? Can you Describe a little bit ? That would be helpful for me .

Comment: with jQuery, per example :
$('li').on('click', function(){
$(this).parent().addClass('ulClass');
});